# Sorting an array of NSDictionaries based on dictionary unique key

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary

Pardon me if this has been answered. All answers I've come across address sorting an array of dictionaries using the **same** key. This is not the case. A UIView, using a UITableView (grouped) has tblData and sections. tblData get's its data from an array of objects.
I can sort the array using a comparator but changes are not reflected no matter what I've tried.
This is the method that creates the data:

```
   if (myAppointment!=nil){
        if (myAppointment.OBSERVATIONS!=nil){
            [self.tblData removeAllObjects];
            @synchronized(self.myAppointment){
                for (Observations *tmpObs in [self.myAppointment OBSERVATIONS]){
                    NSMutableString *tmpHdr = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Observation made on: "];
                    [tmpHdr appendString:tmpObs.TIME];
                    [self.tblData setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:tmpObs.TYPE, tmpObs.NOTE, nil] forKey:tmpHdr];
                }
            }
        }
        self.sections = [[self.tblData allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    }
    [self.GroupTblView reloadData];
```

When I try to sort the myAppointment.OBSERVATIONS, I can verify they are sorted. Yet when I try to reload the data hoping it has been sorted, no changes take place:

```
        [self.tblData removeAllObjects];
        [self.myAppointment.OBSERVATIONS sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareByType:)];                
        for (Observations *tmpObs in self.myAppointment.OBSERVATIONS){   
            NSMutableString *tmpHdr = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Observation made on: "];
            [tmpHdr appendString:tmpObs.TIME];
            [self.tblData setObject:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:tmpObs.TYPE, tmpObs.NOTE, nil] forKey:tmpHdr];
        }
        self.sections = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.tblData allKeys]];
        [self.GroupTblView reloadData];
```

It is my understanding that sections are not being sorted, or not being updated.
As you can see from above, the dictionary key changes with each "Observation" and therefore its not as simple to sort, as it would normally be, by using NSSortDescriptor.
Is there a way around this, by lets say, using a block + sortedArrayUsingComparator ?

EDIT:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *GroupTblView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *tblData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *sections;
```

They are all synthesized and allocated at the initWithNib method.

Comment: Can you specify which are @properties and how they are declared?

Comment: It really feels like you are trying reinvent CoreData and NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: I don't see any connection between the sorting of `OBSERVATIONS` and the ordering of the keys in `tblData` if that's what you're expecting.  The dictionary has no predictable order no matter how its insertions are arranged.

Comment: Phillip Mills, you are absolutely right. And what I've missed is that dictionary key value plays little importance. I've found a way to sort the sections directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this example was a bit silly, I attribute my problem to long hours of work. If anyone is ever interested in sorting the tableData used by UITableView in grouped mode, here is how I did it:

```
        self.sections = [[self.tblData allKeys] 
                         sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b){
                                        // a is a section (a key from the Dictionary), b is another section (another key)
                                        NSArray *a_arr = [self.tblData objectForKey:a];
                                        NSArray *b_arr = [self.tblData objectForKey:b];
                                        // We know that the first item in the array is always the type
                                        return [[a_arr objectAtIndex:0] compare:[b_arr objectAtIndex:0]];
                                        }];
        [self.GroupTblView reloadData];
```

Bear in mind, objectAtIndex:0 is MY observation.TYPE (see above code). Therefore if you know the index of your sorting key in the array within the dictionary object, you can access it, find it (using a block) and use it for sorting.